# chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted) in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

i want to create database in sdcard or external sdcard for this i have try this code and using this i have successfully created database in sdcard but in logcat it give me warning like below

**Logcat**

> 07-18 14:18:22.140: W/FileUtils(8595): Failed to
>   chmod(/mnt/sdcard/peakmedia/DB_PMD): libcore.io.ErrnoException: chmod
>   failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

**DB_Helper.java**

```
public class DB_Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DB_Helper(Context context) 
    {   
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() 
                       + File.separator + DB_Constant.DB.FILE_DIR 
                       + File.separator + DB_Constant.DB.DATABASENAME, null, DB_Constant.DB.DB_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        String  query=String.format(DB_Constant.CREATE_TABLE_QUERY.CREATE_MYFILES_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(query);


        query=String.format(DB_Constant.CREATE_TABLE_QUERY.CREATE_MYUSERS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(query);

        query=String.format(DB_Constant.CREATE_TABLE_QUERY.CREATE_MYPLAYLIST_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(query);

        query=String.format(DB_Constant.CREATE_TABLE_QUERY.CREATE_MYDEVICE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(query);

    }

     @Override
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
     {
            if(newVersion > oldVersion)
            {   

                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DB_Constant.TABLE.MYFILES);
                onCreate(db);

                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DB_Constant.TABLE.MYUSERS);
                onCreate(db);

                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DB_Constant.TABLE.MYPLAYLIST);
                onCreate(db);

                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ DB_Constant.TABLE.MYDEVICE);
                onCreate(db);

            }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just solved this problem.

You have to let your app join linux build to grant it SYSTEM permission.

1. add this line into Android.mk

   `LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform`
2. add this into manifest node of `AndroidManifest.xml`

   `android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"`
3. Generate apk and push it into /system/app/
4. Now you can try to run

   ```
   final String command = "chmod 777 /data/ena";
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   ```

   or

   ```
   File file = new File("/data/ena");
   if (file.exists()) {
       boolean result = file.setExecutable(true);
       Log.e(TAG, "trpb67, RESULT IS " + result);
   }
   ```

   value of result should be true

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I met same problem like Mahesh(appear same warn message, insert data from SQL server to SQLite, 2 tables should receive data in SQLite, but only 1 table received data, another table is empty).

But Today I try to insert data from SQL server into 2 tables of SQLite in SD Card again, this time, 2 table received data.

The only difference is EMULATOR setting.

**Enlarge SD card space setting, from few MB to 8GB, reference picture.**
[emulator setting photo](http://d.share.photo.xuite.net/hung2075/1d21feb/19171198/1050089069_l.jpg)

Although warning also appear, but inserting work success.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your device is connected in MTP usb mode. Sometimes a previous connection of MTP mode can cause this problem. Just restart device and check if it works.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the owner (chown) of this folder. Currently the app/you is not the owner of that folder in where you want to install the db.

So you have to do something like

```
sudo chown -R theuser /mnt/sdcard/peakmedia/DB_PMD
```