# DownloadManager doesn't receive download complete action

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-download-manager

I have an intent service that downloads a file in the background, a broadcast receiver is registered to listen for the download completion, but never gets in the `onReceive()` function of the receiver.  The file seems to finish downloading, I can see it in the file explorer, and get a message from the DownloadManager with status SUCCESS.  Right before the download success message I'm getting an error `Failed to chmod /mnt/internal_sd/../filedownloaded`

Intent started from main activity onCreate:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
startService(i);
```

Intent service:

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService  {

    DownloadManager downloadManager;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
        registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);
        downloadFile();
    }

    void downloadFile(Uri downloadUri) {
        downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
        request.setTitle("My Andorid App Download");
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getApplicationContext(), null, sku + ".apk");

        long downloadNum = downloadManager.enqueue(request);        
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
            System.out.println("does not get in here.");
            long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
            Uri u = downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(id);
        }
    };
}
```

manifest:

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.MyIntentService"
    android:exported="false">

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />                 
    </intent-filter>

</service>
```

It sounds like a permissions issue with the failed to chmod error, but I can't quite figure out what.

Comment: You might want to have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823861/chmod-failed-eperm-operation-not-permitted-in-android

Comment: Don't understand your code. Why are you registering a broacast receiver if the intent should be managed by the IntentService? Do you get the onHandleIntent called or not?

Comment: Sorry, I originally posted some snippets, I edited it to hopefully make it more clear.  I do get inside the `onHandleIntent()`, and there is a log file saying the DownloadManager completed the download with status SUCCESS, it just isn't broadcasting the download completion.  This worked before when I ran the class as its own activity, but now I want to run it in the background while another activity is already running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem.  You shouldn't have a broadcast receiver in an intent service, since the intent service runs on a separate thread it will execute everything in your `onHandleIntent()` then go away.  My intent service was gone before the download manager could broadcast the download completion.

Comment: I have same problem, I have to download file in back thread and after complete download, do some other work, so.. what should I do ?